# ZXing java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/zxing/WriterException Error

Tags: java, maven, qr-code, zxing

#### Project Context

Currently trying to generate QR codes to implement some information within it, that includes data (such as a student ID number, first name, last name) and MAC address of local computer (testing on my desktop computer for now, but will be applied to individual raspberry Pis).

#### Error in Question

[image]

#### The Java Code

Ignore the data link input, this is for test purposes only.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{        
    MACFinder GM = new MACFinder();
    GM.getMac();
    
    System.out.println();
    
    try
    {
        GM.generateQRCodeImage();
    }
    catch (WriterException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Couldn't generate QR code, WriterException...");
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Couldn't generate QR code, IOException...");
    }
    catch (NotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("This library couldn't be found... (ZXing)");
    }
}

    public void generateQRCodeImage() throws WriterException, IOException, NotFoundException
{
    String data = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qzYpgbP8RHA";
    String filepath = "C:\\Users\\JmJ23\\Documents\\Code\\Internship Code";
    
    QRCodeWriter qrCodeWriter = new QRCodeWriter();
    BitMatrix bitMatrix = qrCodeWriter.encode(data, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 250, 250);

    Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(filepath);
    MatrixToImageWriter.writeToPath(bitMatrix, "PNG", path);
}
```

#### POM.xml Dependencies

```
    <dependency>  
    <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>  
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>  
    <version>3.3.0</version>  
</dependency> 

<dependency>  
    <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>  
    <artifactId>javase</artifactId>  
    <version>3.3.0</version>  
</dependency>
```

I understand that a NoClassDefFoundError is when a library/class is called but the class in question is not found at runtime... but why would this be the case if I have installed it into my Maven project? As a note I cleaned the project multiple times but with no progress. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your build looks fine. You didn't say how you build and run this, but I expect you just tried to build a .jar and run that .jar, without building all of its dependencies into it. You need something like the Maven assembly plugin.

Comment: Yes that's exactly how I was initially building it, I thought as I had an executable jar all the dependencies should be installed in it. Sorted it by the Maven shade assembly plugin. Thanks.